# Jquery Mobile Listview- to remove data-autodividers attribute on completion of a event

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, siebel

We are adding data-autodivider attribute in  through this code in siebel Open UI mobile application:

```
J = this.GetJQMListId();
    // Add attribute "data-autodividers: true" to GROUP the list
    J.attr({
        "data-role": "listview",
        "data-inset": "true",
        "data-autodividers": "true"
    });
    J.listview();
```

Above code is working fine. It is showing us the list divider.

On completion of a event we want to remove the grouping banner (list divider) from the listview.
We are changing the attribute and refreshing the listview.

```
           J = this.GetJQMListId();

                J.attr({
                    "data-autodividers": "false"
                });
                J.listview("refresh");
```

But we are not able to get the desired output.
How to remove the list divider from listview dynamically?

Comment: `J.find(".ui-li-divider").remove().end().listview("refresh");`

Comment: Hi Omar, Thanks for the reply. But this approach is not working i.e list-divider is not getting removed.

Comment: if `J` returns _listview object_ then it should work. replace `J` with `$("#listviewID")` and try again/

Comment: Working fiddle on Omar's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/4us5w/